# responsive image rollover with CSS

Tags: css, sass

Im trying to create a rollover effect on a bunch of responsive image blog posts that prompt the user to click the image. At the moment Im currently having two issues

**1)** I can't figure out how to get the orange box area to only cover the width of the image (keeping in mind this image width and height are not fixed dimensions)

**2)** I don't know how to get the "read more" text to sit exactly in the middle of the orange box (again keeping in mind this box isn't a fixed height or width)

**currently it looks like this:**

[image]

HTML

```
    <div class="post">
            <div class="view thumbnail">
                <img src="http://static.designspiration.net/data/l/4912616924_FIyt0Hpa_l.jpg">
                <div class="mask"> 
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h1><a href="#">The Gent</a></h1>
            <p>Some great work from this year's LFA Futures competitions winners have been announced: Gerwyn Davies, Oliver Haupt...</p>
            <b class="time-ago">2 Months Ago</b>
            <b class="date">11.11.13</b>
        </div>
    </div>
```

SASS

```
.post {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 2%;
 display: inline-block;

.thumbnail {
    .mask {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: visible;
        background: rgba(255, 133, 66, 0.8);
        @include transition-property(all);
        @include transition-duration(0.3s);
        @include transition-timing-function(linear);
        z-index: 999999;
    }

    a.info {
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0;
        top: 85px;
        @include transition-property(all);
        @include transition-duration(0.3s);
        @include transition-timing-function(linear);
    }

    &:hover {
        .mask {
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1;
            background: rgba(255, 133, 66, 0.8);
            z-index: 999999;
        }
        a.info {
            opacity: 1;
            @include transition-property(all);
            @include transition-duration(0.3s);
            @include transition-timing-function(linear);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this: add top: 50%; margin-top: -25%; to a.info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I don't know about SASS but I create this demo for you with CSS :

**http://jsfiddle.net/2kfUr/2/**

Here I made this additional changes:

- First make the `thumbnail` be the relative parent for the absolute position of the mask:

  ```
  .thumbnail {
    position:relative;
  }
  ```
- Then make the `mask` be at top and align text horizontally :

  ```
  .thumbnail .mask {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
  }
  ```
- And for the vertical align use this:

  ```
  .mask a.info {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
  .mask:before {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    content:" ";
    vertical-align:middle;    
  }
  ```

*Edit*

- Add `inline-block` to make the container take the width of img:

  ```
  .thumbnail {
    display:inline-block;
  }
  ```

New demo http://jsfiddle.net/2kfUr/4/